# matches method of str not found

Tags: string, rust

I am using [rayon](https://crates.io/crates/rayon) to perform parallel iteration on a text and trying to output strings that contains a particular character. I am using the [`matches()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.matches): 
[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ecf30a516803f8968a6da22b34201c6b)

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let text =
        "Some are born great, some achieve greatness, and some have greatness thrust upon them."
            .to_string();
    check(text, 's');
}

fn check(text: String, ch: char) {
    let words: Vec<_> = text.split_whitespace().collect();
    let words_with_ch: Vec<_> = words.par_iter().map(|ch| words.matches(ch)).collect();
    println!(
        "The following words contain the letter {:?}: {:?}",
        ch, words_with_ch
    );
}
```

but its showing an error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `matches` found for type `std::vec::Vec<&str>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:12:65
   |
12 |     let words_with_ch: Vec<_> = words.par_iter().map(|ch| words.matches(ch)).collect();
   |                                                                 ^^^^^^^
```

How can I solve this compile error?

Comment: It should be `.map(|w| {w.matches(ch)})`

Comment: Please show the code (and probably the error) in the question itself. The link-only questions, like the link-only answers, are generally discouraged.

Comment: ... from the other hand you need `filter`, not `map` and `str.contains`

Comment: Please next time take more time to format your question, read [ask], it's totally good to have a playground link but always include the code in the question, also don't forget to use format tool of playground and include the error in the question itself. Also, be more precise, "an external crate to perform parallel iteration", just put a link to the crate you are using, "that i found in the standard str documentation", link to the doc.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @zerkms, filter() would be a good function to use to solve this.

The filter works on an iterator. split_whitespace() creates the iterator, which can then be passed to filter().

```
fn main() {
    let text =
        "Some are born great, some achieve greatness, and some have greatness thrust upon them."
            .to_string();
    check(text, 's');
}

fn check(text: String, ch: char) {
    let words_with_ch: Vec<_> = text
        .split_whitespace()
        .filter(|w| w.contains(ch))
        .collect();
    println!(
        "The following words contain the letter {:?}: {:?}",
        ch, words_with_ch
    );
}
```